# How to extract the decimal part from a floating point number in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, decimal, numbers

How can we extract the decimal part of a floating point number and store the decimal part and the integer part into two separate integer variables?

Comment: I don't see how you could put the decimal part into an integer unless you knew how many digits you wanted to keep. Could you give a few examples?

Comment: i want to get the decimal part as integer for any inputting value.
so the number of digits in the deciaml part cannot  predict.

Comment: like if u input 16.25
i want to get 25 in an integer value
also if teh nuber is 0.3215769
i want to get 3215769 in an integer 
like that

Comment: reading into a string, then checking to see whether the string is a double (questions exist on SO that are answered saying how to do that), and then getting the stuff after the ".". what about that? or do you need to read other formats too (10e-5)?

Comment: is thre any othe r method for doing this other than using string manipulation.??

Comment: i didnt meant these format(10e-5).i meant the exact number..

Comment: How/why do you want to represent the fractional part in an integer?

Comment: Well, floor() or casting will get you the integer part easily, but what do you actually expect to store in the "decimal" part? Not even including issues like floating point (im)precision, what do you want to happen when your candidate float is a repeating fraction or an irrational number?

Comment: What if you have a bunch of zeros after the decimal point? They can't be represented unless they are in a string--an int wouldn't work for that.

Comment: How would you distinguish the decimal fractions in 1.5 and 1.005?

Comment: You mean the fractional part of the decimal. Decimal is just short-hand for Decimal Fraction, and a Decimal is actually any base 10 number because when you add two decimals you will always get a decimal result, which may or may not have a fractional place such as 1/2 + 1/2 = 1. A decimal can also refer to a decimal 0 through 9, so saying the fractional portion of the decimal is a decimal when each digit is a decimal then is not honest. The fractional portion of the decimal is the correct terminology.

Comment: "Decimalpart" is ambiguous, and arguably erroneous.  I believe that you want the "fractional part".

Answer (score 107):

You use the `modf` function:

```
double integral;
double fractional = modf(some_double, &integral);
```

You can also cast it to an integer, but be warned you may overflow the integer. The result is not predictable then.

Comment: @penu It's because you are using `%d` for printing `double`. Here is the working code: http://codepad.org/kPGKtcZi

Comment: This code truncates 123.456745693850 from 0.45674569385 to 0.456746

Comment: @Richard you can open a new stackoverflow question to ask why it would do that on your machine. I have no idea.

Comment: On my machine, man pages for modf gives me the signature `double modf(double x, double *iptr);`, but I have some compiler implementation headers which uses float instead of double. Maybe this is why truncation to float may happen... I think I'll prefer the int cast + subtraction solution to avoid this issue...

Answer (score 70):

Try this:

```
int main() {
  double num = 23.345;
  int intpart = (int)num;
  double decpart = num - intpart;
  printf("Num = %f, intpart = %d, decpart = %f\n", num, intpart, decpart);
}
```

For me, it produces:

```
Num = 23.345000, intpart = 23, decpart = 0.345000
```

Which appears to be what you're asking for.

Comment: the first part is correct
but wish to get the result as decimal part as 345000 integer

Comment: but i want to get the deciaml part as Integer value
which means decpart=345000

Comment: int decpart = 100000*(num - intpart);

Comment: This method is susceptible to some nasty floating-point problems. Try setting `num = 1.1` for a quick example. As a floating-point number `decpart` cannot represent `0.1`.

Comment: Regarding the second line of the method: did C require a cast back in '09? Or is it just there for clarification?

Answer (score 18):

The quick "in a nut shell" most obvious answer seems like:

```
#define N_DECIMAL_POINTS_PRECISION (1000) // n = 3. Three decimal points.

float f = 123.456;
int integerPart = (int)f;
int decimalPart = ((int)(f*N_DECIMAL_POINTS_PRECISION)%N_DECIMAL_POINTS_PRECISION);
```

You would change how many decimal points you want by changing the `N_DECIMAL_POINTS_PRECISION` to suit your needs.

Comment: Just for fun. Let's do a thought experiement:

The more obfuscated and complex ( see "hard to maintain code" ) solution could go as far as [bit slicing][1] the float or double to get the actual ["integerBits" and "fractionalBits"][2].

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of why you would do this... maybe this method would have the advantage of capturing the integer and decimal parts directly without losing any of the precision due to floating point rounding.

Comment: Here is some incomplete pseudo code to give you the idea:

    #define BIT_MASK1 /* not sure */
    #define SHIFT     /* not sure */
    #define BIT_MASK2 /* not sure */
    
    float f = 123.456;
    uint32_t * tmp = (uint32_t *)&f;
    
    int integerPart = (int)f;

Comment: int decimalPart = (((*tmp)&BIT_MASK1)>>SHIFT)&BIT_MASK2;

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_mask
  [2]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)

Answer (score 3):

I created a subroutine one using a double float, it returns 2 integer values.

```
void double2Ints(double f, int p, int *i, int *d)
{ 
  // f = float, p=decimal precision, i=integer, d=decimal
  int   li; 
  int   prec=1;

  for(int x=p;x>0;x--) 
  {
    prec*=10;
  };  // same as power(10,p)

  li = (int) f;              // get integer part
  *d = (int) ((f-li)*prec);  // get decimal part
  *i = li;
}

void test()
{ 
  double df = 3.14159265;
  int   i,d;
  for(int p=2;p<9;p++)
  {
    double2Ints(df, p, &i,&d); printf("d2i (%d) %f = %d.%d\r\n",p, df,i,d);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the floating number to subtract the *floor*ed value to get its fractional part:

```
double fractional = some_double - floor(some_double);
```

This prevents the typecasting to an integer, which may cause **overflow** if the floating number is very large that an integer value could not even contain it.

Also for **negative values**, this code gives you the **positive fractional part** of the floating number since *floor()* [computes the largest integer value not greater than the input value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/floor).

Comment: Try it with a number such as 10.2346789358 and you will get 0.2346789357999999 in return which is wrong.

Comment: In the context of `double`, 0.2346789357999999 is one of several correct answers, depending on exactly how the value is encoded, compiler flags, architecture, processor flags, etc. Floating point types are not decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char* inStr = "123.4567";         //the number we want to convert
    char* endptr;                     //unused char ptr for strtod

    char* loc = strchr(inStr, '.');
    long mantissa = strtod(loc+1, endptr);
    long whole = strtod(inStr, endptr);

    printf("whole: %d \n", whole);     //whole number portion
    printf("mantissa: %d", mantissa);  //decimal portion

}
```

http://codepad.org/jyHoBALU

Output:

```
whole: 123 
mantissa: 4567
```

Comment: Your code won’t work on 16 bits platforms where longs are 32 bits and long double are 53 bits.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using string is the correct way to go in this case, since you don't know a priori the number of digits in the decimal part. But, it won't work for all cases (e.g. 1.005), as mentioned before by @SingleNegationElimination. Here is my take on this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s_value[60], s_integral[60], s_fractional[60];
    int i, found = 0, count = 1, integral, fractional;

    scanf("%s", s_value);

    for (i = 0; s_value[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (!found)
        {
            if (s_value[i] == '.')
            {
                found = 1;
                s_integral[i] = '\0';
                continue;
            }
            s_integral[i] = s_value[i];
            count++;
        }
        else
            s_fractional[i - count] = s_value[i];
    }
    s_fractional[i - count] = '\0';

    integral = atoi(s_integral);
    fractional = atoi(s_fractional);
    printf("value = %s, integral = %d, fractional = %d\n",
        s_value, integral, fractional);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You solved the problem in a way nobody should ever attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
float num;
int intgPart;
float fracPart;
printf("Enter the positive floating point number: ");
scanf("%f", &num);

intgPart = (int)num;
fracPart = num - intgPart;
```

The fractional part can be obtained by subtracting an integral part from the original double value.

Answer (score 1):

My printf() didn't support formatting for floats. This was my solution to print it as two integers. Change 100 in to what you like to increase the precision.

I found this one

```
#define DEC(f) (uint32_t)(100*((f)-(float)((uint32_t)(f))))
#define INT(f) (uint32_t)(f)

DEC(3.1416..) = 14 (int) 
INT(3.1416..) = 3 (int)
```

Let me know what you think of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best idea is to solve the problem while the data is in String format. If you have the data as String, you may parse it according to the decimal point. You extract the integral and decimal part as Substrings and then convert these substrings to actual integers.

Comment: Converting it to a string just for this is a bit silly, but if it were a string originally then this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I made this function, it seems to work fine:

```
#include <math.h>

void GetFloattoInt (double fnum, long precision, long *pe, long *pd)
{
  long pe_sign;
  long intpart;
  float decpart;

  if(fnum>=0)
  {
    pe_sign=1;
  }
  else
  {
    pe_sign=-1;
  }

  intpart=(long)fnum;
  decpart=fnum-intpart;

  *pe=intpart;  
  *pd=(((long)(decpart*pe_sign*pow(10,precision)))%(long)pow(10,precision));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the first decimal value, the solution is really simple.

**Here's an explanatory example:**

```
int leftSideOfDecimalPoint = (int) initialFloatValue; // The cast from float to int keeps only the integer part

int temp = (int) initialFloatValue * 10;
int rightSideOfDecimalPoint = temp % 10;
```

Say for example we have an initial float value of 27.8 .

- By just casting the initial float value to an int, you discard the fraction part and only keep the integer part.
- By multiplying the initial float value by 10 we get a result of 278.0, then by casting this result to int, gives you the value of 278
- If we divide 278 by 10, we get 27.8, of which the remainder is 8, which is the value at the right side of the decimal point. Thus use modulus.

This technique can then be used to get the following decimal characters by using for example 100 instead of 10, and so on.

---

Just take note that if you use this technique on real-time systems, for example to display it on a 7-segment display, it may not work properly because we are multiplying with a float value, where multiplication takes a lot of overhead time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
Int main ()
{
float f=56.75;
int a=(int)f;
int result=(f-a)*100;
printf ("integer = %d\n decimal part to integer 
 =%d\n",result);
}
Output:- 
integer =56
decimal part to integer = 75
```

Comment: You assume here that decimal part is only two digits wide. That may not be case.

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Suppose A  is your integer then (int)A, means casting the number to an integer and will be the integer part, the other is (A - (int)A)*10^n, here n is the number of decimals to keep.

Answer (score -1):

Even I was thinking how to do it. But I found a way.
Try this code

```
printf("Enter a floating number");
scanf("%d%c%d", &no, &dot, &dec);
printf("Number=%d Decimal part=%d", no, dec);
```

Output:-

```
Enter a floating number
23.13
Number=23 Decimal part=13
```

Comment: Won't work for 23.003

Comment: This is hard-coded. This answer isn't useful at all.

Answer (score -2):

```
cout<<"enter a decimal number\n";
cin>>str;
for(i=0;i<str.size();i++)
{
    if(str[i]=='.')
    break;
}

for(j=i+1;j<str.size();j++)
{
    cout<<str[j];
}
```

Comment: Could you add some comments to your answer?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This answer is not helpful to the questioner. The code is entirely wrong!
Why are you using Strings?