# Check whether a float number contains decimals or not

Tags: floating-point, decimal

How can I check whether a float number contains decimals like 2.10, 2.45, 12382.66 and not 2.00 , 12382.00. I want to know if the number is "round" or not. How can I do that programmatically?

Comment: By looking at them?  If you want a programmatic solution, then give us more information.

Comment: (And the language you're working in.)

Answer (score 62):

Using modulus will work:

```
if(num % 1 != 0) do something!
// eg. 23.5 % 1 = 0.5
```

Comment: Great answer, but this will not work in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php): "Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing."

Answer (score 8):

I use this c function for objective c

```
BOOL CGFloatHasDecimals(float f) {
    return (f-(int)f != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you care only about two decimals, get the remainder by computing `bool hasDecimals = (((int)(round(x*100))) % 100) != 0;`

In generic case get a fractional part as described in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499939/extract-decimal-part-from-a-floating-point-number-in-c) and compare it to 0.

Comment: This worked beautifully for me. I'm using Objective-C btw. As long as you know how many decimals you care about evaluating, this is simple and does the job. And you can modify it by by multiplying 10 by the power of how many decimal spots you care about, to replace the occurrences of "100" in the above sample, to make it even more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
  float num = 23.345f;
  int intpart = (int)num;
  float decpart = num - intpart;
  if(decpart == 0.0f)
  {
    //Contains no decimals
  }
  else
  {
     //Number contains decimals
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        convert(50.0f);
        convert(13.59f);

    }

    private static void convert(float mFloat){
        if(mFloat - (int)mFloat != 0)
            System.out.println(mFloat);
        else
            System.out.println((int)mFloat);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`PHP` solution:

```
function hasDecimals($x)
{
    return floatval($x) - intval($x) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Scala** you can use `isWhole()` or `isValidInt()` to check if number has no fractional part:

```
object Example {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    val hasDecimals = 3.14.isWhole //false
    val hasDecimals = 3.14.isValidInt//false

  }
}
```