# Check if decimal contains decimal places by looking at the bytes

Tags: c#, decimal

There is a similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668407/how-to-check-whether-a-float-number-contains-decimals-like-2-10-2-45-12382-66).  Sometimes that solution gives exceptions because the numbers might be to large.

I think that if there is a way of looking at the bytes of a decimal number it will be more efficient. For example a decimal number has to be represented by some n number of bytes. For example an Int32 is represented by 32 bits and all the numbers that start with the bit of 1 are negative. Maybe there is some kind of similar relationship with decimal numbers. How could you look at the bytes of a decimal number? or the bytes of an integer number?

Comment: Don't you mean the `bits` of a 32bit int, and not the bytes, as a byte is just 8bits, so you'd want to look at the bits...

Comment: If you're looking for efficiency, `decimal` probably isn't part of the solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are really talking about **decimal** numbers (as opposed to **floating-point numbers**), then [Decimal.GetBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx) will let you look at the individual bits of a decimal. The MSDN page also contains a description of the meaning of the bits.

On the other hand, if you just want to check whether a number has a fractional part or not, doing a simple

```
var hasFractionalPart = (myValue - Math.Round(myValue) != 0)
```

is *much* easier than decoding the binary structure. This should work for decimals as well as classic floating-point data types such as **float** or **double**. In the latter case, due to floating-point rounding error, it might make sense to check for `Math.Abs(myValue - Math.Round(myValue)) < someThreshold` instead of comparing to `0`.

Comment: `myValue - Math.Truncate(myValue)` might be slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a reasonably efficient way of getting the 'decimal' value of a `decimal` type you can just mod it by one.

```
decimal number = 4.75M;
decimal fractionalPart = number % 1; 
Console.WriteLine(fractionalPart); //will print 0.75
```

While it may not be the theoretically optimal solution, it'll be quite fast, and almost certainly fast enough for your purposes (far better than string manipulation and parsing, which is a common naive approach).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Decimal.GetBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx) in order to retrieve the bits from a decimal structure.

The MSDN page linked above details how they are laid out in memory:

> The binary representation of a Decimal number consists of a 1-bit sign, a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the integer number and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction. The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent ranging from 0 to 28.
>
> The return value is a four-element array of 32-bit signed integers.
>
> The first, second, and third elements of the returned array contain the low, middle, and high 32 bits of the 96-bit integer number.
>
> The fourth element of the returned array contains the scale factor and sign. It consists of the following parts:
>
> Bits 0 to 15, the lower word, are unused and must be zero.
>
> Bits 16 to 23 must contain an exponent between 0 and 28, which indicates the power of 10 to divide the integer number.
>
> Bits 24 to 30 are unused and must be zero.
>
> Bit 31 contains the sign; 0 meaning positive, and 1 meaning negative.

Answer (score 2):

Going with Oded's detailed info to use GetBits, I came up with this

```
const int EXP_MASK = 0x00FF0000;
bool hasDecimal = (Decimal.GetBits(value)[3] & EXP_MASK) != 0x0;
```