# Getting the first decimal place of a number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, math

I have a number for example: `2.4444444`. I need to get first digit after the dot -- in my case it's `4`. How to implement it?

Comment: convert it as string and separate the string after '.'Now get the first indexvale from string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
( (int)(floor( fabs( num ) * 10 ) ) ) % 10
```

Comment: You're welcome :) You can even make a constant, let's say `int nNumberAfterDecimalPoint = 1;` and instead of hard-coding `10` (as in my solution), you can make it `( (int)(floor( fabs( num ) * ( 10 * nNumberAfterDecimalPoint ) ) ) % 10`. This will make it a little more flexible and you'll be able to get not only the first digit after the decimal point, but whichever you like only by changing the constant :) Anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Chech these out! Tried it for you hope it helps

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
 {
  int b;
  float a;
  a=2.4444; 'load some value
  b=(int)a;  'typecast it into integer you get 2 into b variable
  a=a-b;     ' subtract b from a and you will get decimal point value 0.4444        
  a=a*10;    ' multiplying with 10 gives 4.444
  b=(int)a;  ' now apply the same logic again 
  printf("%d",b); 'outputs 4  
 }
```

**Update** written these function using these link

[Extract decimal part from a floating point number in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499939/extract-decimal-part-from-a-floating-point-number-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

it could be as simple as

```
num*10%10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(int)(num * 10) - ((int)num) * 10
```

Comment: @Wevah is right, you need both - `floor` and `(f)abs`. `(int)` will round the number  (for example - 5.6 would become 6 )

Comment: Typecasting to int doesn't round numbers, it truncates them. At least that's how it's done in almost any computer language I'm aware of. I doubt Object-C is an exception.