# randomizing decimal portion of a double

Tags: java

I have the following method which takes in GPS coordinates as strings and converts them to doubles with a maximum of 6 decimal points. Now I'm trying to randomize the decimal points starting from the first decimal.

```
public void randomizeCoordinate(String latString, String lonString)
{
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(latString);
    double lon = Double.parseDouble(lonString);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    for (Number n : Arrays.asList(lat, lon))
    {
        Double d = n.doubleValue();
        System.out.println(df.format(d));
    }
}
```

For example if I have 2.34 I want the randomized to be something like 2.493473 or 2.294847 or 2.346758

The first decimal point in which in this case is 3 from 2.34 should only change a maximum of one digit. Up or down randomly. The leading decimal points can change to anything in a random fashion.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Random rand = new Random();
double x = ...;

x = ((int)(x*10) + rand.nextDouble()*2 - 1)/10.0;
```

Multiply by 10 and truncate to get the digits including the first decimal, add a random number between -1 and 1, scale back.

Note that your doubles will not have just 6 decimal digits; these numbers aren't decimal numbers. For output to show 6 decimals you'll need to format the number by using a format requesting 6 decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

You could find a random number between -100,000 and 100,000, divide it by 1,000,000 then add it to your original number.

It would effectively make your number up to +0.1 or -0.1 different, but in theory could return 0 which would result in the same number.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.random()`, or a subclass of `java.util.Random`...

```
 d += 0.1 * (Math.random() * 2 - 1);
```

That would give you a range from 2.24 to 2.44 for your example.

If you really want a range from 2.20 to 2.39999999..., see @laune's answer.

Comment: Hmm, you are adding values in the range -0.01 .. 0.01. You better fix that.

Comment: fixed, thanks. And of course either of our answers assumes "leading" really means "trailing".

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get the min and max ranges for the `double` that you have entered and generates another random `decimal` part which is then added to the `int` part of the original number.

```
    // Example double
    double lat = Double.parseDouble("2.59");

    // Get the first decimal place
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164487/getting-the-first-decimal-place-of-a-number
    int first_dec = ( (int)(Math.floor( Math.abs( lat ) * 10 ) ) ) % 10;

    // Get the min and max range
    double min = (double)(first_dec - 1)/10;
    double max = (double)(first_dec + 1)/10;

    // Generate a random number in that range
    Random rand = new Random();
    double randomValue = min + (max - min) * rand.nextDouble();

    // Printing for clarifying
    System.out.println("min = " + min + " : max = " + max + " : randomValue = " + randomValue);

    // Format as required
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
    System.out.println(df.format((int)lat + randomValue));
```

For the example double (2.59), this generated the following on multiple runs

```
min = 0.4 : max = 0.6 : randomValue = 0.5189434537923328
2.518943
min = 0.4 : max = 0.6 : randomValue = 0.5283024116190669
2.528302
min = 0.4 : max = 0.6 : randomValue = 0.44384090285085204
2.443841
```