# Retrieve the decimal part of a double

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract decimal part from a floating point number in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499939/extract-decimal-part-from-a-floating-point-number-in-c)

I would like retrieve the decimal part of a double in the most efficient way.

Something like this:

```
double a = 1.5;
double decimal_part = a -1 ; // decimal_part = 0.5
```

How retrieve and store in a variable in a really efficient way the .5 (decimal part of a) ?

Comment: How do you want to deal with negative values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [modf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/modf/) function:

```
double integer_part;
double decimal_part = modf(a, &integer_part);
```

Comment: The pointer supplied to `modf()` is not allowed to be `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `modf` function from `math.h` for `double` and `modff` for `float`.

```
#include <math.h>

double val = 3.14159;
double integral_part;
double fractional_part;

/*
 * integral_part will be 3.0
 * fractional_part will be 0.14159
 */
fractional_part = modf(val, &integral_part);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double a = 5.6;
double f = a - int(a); // int(a) chops off fraction
```

you have to make sure ranges are sane st int doesn't overflow.

Comment: Not safe, the int conversion can overflow.