# Calculation not coming out as a percentage

Tags: ios, textfield, percentage

Can some one help with a calculation please.

The following code is from two TextFields and inputs into a third one (endmonth1year1percentageTextField).  When i put in the numbers (100 for the first and 145 for the second) I get an output of 1 instead of 1.45.  What I really need is that 1.45 turned into a percentage as in .45.

```
float x = ([startmonth1year1TextField.text floatValue]);
float c = (([endmonth1year1TextField.text floatValue]) / x);
endmonth1year1percentageTextField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", c];
```

Any help is appreciated.   Thanks

Comment: You need to change @"%2.f" to @"%.2f"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
endmonth1year1percentageTextField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", c];
```

instead of

```
endmonth1year1percentageTextField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", c];
```

(.2f instead of 2.f)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot abou that one.  Can you tell me how to do it as .45 instead of 1.45?  I need it to come out as a percentage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499939/extract-decimal-part-from-a-floating-point-number-in-c