# Get floating/decimal portion of a float

Tags: erlang

I would like:

```
unknown_function(123.456) -> 456
unknown_function(1234.56) -> 56
```

Or

```
unknown_function(123.456) -> "456"
```

Is there a builtin for this? The builtin `trunc/1` does the opposite:

```
2> trunc(123.456).
123
```

There is this answer for C: [Extract decimal part from a floating point number in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499939/extract-decimal-part-from-a-floating-point-number-in-c) and this for Java: [How to get the decimal part of a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017072/how-to-get-the-decimal-part-of-a-float)

Comment: The links you've posted return the decimal part as a float value. Is that what you want? `N = 123.456, N - trunc(N). => 0.45600000000000307`

Comment: I want it as an integer, or a string, but not as a float. The accepted answer in the C one was not what the OP asked for, they clarified in comments. No that is not what  want.

Comment: This is one way but you'll need to set the number of decimal places you want: `lists:nth(2, string:tokens(float_to_list(123.456, [{decimals, 20}]), ".")).`

Comment: @Dogbert that seems to introduce rounding errors first, I wonder if there is a way to avoid that, that produces "45600000000000306954"

Comment: @Dogbert I think I can use what you have to make a good answer, will post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is inspired by @Dogbert's comment

The algorithm doesnt work using native floats due to floating point representation limits and rounding errors.

However, using https://github.com/tim/erlang-decimal:

```
frac_to_denom_int(Num, Denom, Precison) ->
{X, _} = string:to_integer(lists:nth(2, string:tokens(decimal:format(decimal:divide(Num, Denom, [{precision, Precison}])), "."))),
X.
```

E.g.,

```
frac_to_denom_int("1.0", "3.0", 1000).
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
```

If you don't have a frac,

```
d_to_denom_int(D_Tup)->
    string:to_integer(lists:nth(2, string:tokens(decimal:format(D_Tup), "."))).

d_to_denom_int({0, 123456, -3}).
 > 456
```

Answer (score 2):

No there is no BIF for this, but you can do this:

```
decimal_point(X, DecimalDigits) when X < 0 ->
  decimal_point(-X, DecimalDigits);
decimal_point(X, DecimalDigits)->
  (X - trunc(X)) * math:pow(10,DecimalDigits).

> decimal_point(2.33, 2).
33
> decimal_point(-2.33, 2).
33
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @dogbert's comment, passing in one more flag `compact` on the `float_to_list/2` call will help:

```
lists:nth(2, string:tokens(float_to_list(123.456, [{decimals, 10}, compact]), ".")).
% "456"
```

If you go over decimals 14, you'll start to see those rounding errors.